# Keep SQL Server table sorted inside database

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my application I use a simple table that contains the number of times a file was accessed and the date at which it was last accessed.

I'm trying to sort the saved entries so that the files with the highest number of accesses are always on top in the database. Also I would like to sort only the files which have been accessed in the last 7 days.

What method should I use(with execution speed in mind)? Should I maybe write a stored procedure that takes care of the sorting and just call that every time I add or modify an entry? Should I query the entries newer than 7 days in my application, sort them, and add them at the top of the database? Any other methods are most welcome.

Thanks, Catalin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you add a [clustered index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) on the columns that define ordering, SQL Server will use that to physically organize rows in the table.**

However, you should always use an ORDER BY clause in your queries, as the database is not required to return rows in any particular order. The benefit of using a clustered index, however, is that can can reduce the overall cost of sorting rows when they are retrieved and it improves the performing range queries on the indexed columns.

Comment: There is *no* guarantee that the *physical* ordering of rows within the database file will match the order defined by the clustered index. All that a clustered index guarantees is that range queries that are expressed against the same columns as those listed in the clustered index will be satisfiable using fewer lookups than via a non-clustered index. But you are correct to say to always specify an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: My understanding was with a clustered index, records within a single page would be ordered by the cluster key. The net effect, is that while individual pages are not in any particular order on disk, the cost of sorting records is somewhat reduced (it effectively becomes a merge sort operation). But perhaps, I've misunderstood something.

Answer (score 2):

In your question, there is an implicit assumption that a relational database table is somehow ordered. It is not. It represents a **set**. Sets, by definition, are unordered (e.g., the set [a,b,c] is the same set as [b,c,a]).

Therefore, SQL explicitly does not warrant any particular order to a result set, unless one is specified via an ORDER BY clause. Execution of the exact same query without ORDER BY twice in succession could, theoretically, return identical result sets with different ordering (for instance, certain pages of the table might already be in cache and get examine before the execution engine looks at other pages.)

In practice, putting a clustering index on the table (in SQL Server will result) in results being returned in clustered sequence (provided the query uses the clustering index or not index), as the net effect of adding a clustering index is to make the data pages of the table the leaf nodes of the b-tree that is the clustering index. Without a clustering index, the data pages of the table are in a heap and each (non-clustered) index is a b-tree where the leaf nodes are pointers to a data page in the heap.

Back to your question...

Consider the table:

```
create table dbo.PublicFile
(
  id                int          not null ,
  name              varchar(500) not null ,
  access_cnt        int          not null ,
  dt_last_access    datetime     not null ,

  primary key nonclustered (id)   ,
  unique      nonclustered (name) ,

)
```

The two columns access_cnt and dt_last_access are both highly dynamic by your description. Every access of a file will result in an update of these two columns. If you put a clustering index on these, you will encounter performance problems due to the high number of page splits you'll encounter as rows get moved around in the index. (You'll have the same problem with a non-clustered index as well, but the page splits will only affect the index pages, not the data pages, a far smaller column.)

First off, write the query to get the results you want without considering indexing (that's an optimization). This query will give you the list of public files accessed in the last 7 days, ordered in descending sequence by the number of accesses:

```
select *
from dbo.PublicFile f
where f.dt_last_access >= dateadd(day,-7,current_timestamp)
order by f.access_cnt desc , f.name
```

Depending on the size of the data, this might well server as it stands. If you've 4 or 5 million rows, it probably won't. Your DBA will likely want to add an index on the data of last access and the access count. I'd likely use just one index:

```
create nonclustered index PublicFile_IX01
on dbo.PublicFile ( dt_last_access ,
                    access_cnt desc
                  )
```

But there's a certain amount of experimentation involved. Depending on the semantics of the query and the shape of the data, the query optimizer may or may not like it.

Answer (score 1):

You can created a clustered index to keep these in the order you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174523(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The database indexes important columns (and any other columns you specify) so you can ignore the order of the rows in the database and just make sure the proper columns are indexed.  From there, a simple OrderBy in your query will take care of returning the records in the correct order.