# Inserting large amount of data (5k rows) from one table to another shuffles rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I use SQL Sserver 2008.

While inserting large amount of data (about 5k rows) from one table to another shuffles rows. This happens only few times, not always. I have also used `Order by` clause to order the rows.

Is this possible?

The query is shown here:

```
INSERT INTO R_G_23 (Sr_No, Date, Item_Code, Item_Name, Received_Qty, Invoice_No, Invoice_Date, Supplier_ECC_No, Supplier_Name, Supplier_Address, Range_and_Division, Issued_Challan_No, Issued_Date, Issued_Qty, Ar_In_No_Date, Qty,Doc_Part, Otherwise_Qty, Balance_Qty, Excise_Officer_Initial, GRN_No)
   SELECT 
       Sr_No, Date, Item_Code, Item_Name, Received_Qty, Invoice_No, Invoice_Date, Supplier_ECC_No, Supplier_Name, Supplier_Address, Range_and_Division, Issued_Challan_No, Issued_Date, Issued_Qty, Ar_In_No_Date, Qty,Doc_Part, Otherwise_Qty, Balance_Qty, Excise_Officer_Initial, GRN_No
   FROM 
       Temp_R_G_23 
   ORDER BY 
       Sr_No asc;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep SQL Server table sorted inside database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595229/keep-sql-server-table-sorted-inside-database)

Comment: Relational database are not required to keep data in order or return the data in the order in which it is in the table. However sqlserver has a method to keep the data in the table ordered see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595229

Comment: You **NEVER** have any guaranteed order ***unless*** you explicitly specify an `ORDER BY` when you select from a table. So yes - if you need an order - you **must** specify an `ORDER BY`. Also: the actual storage of the rows in the database is without any ordering, so using an `ORDER BY` on an `INSERT` is really pointless - the data will **not** be stored in that order anyway

Comment: thnx  Eelke and LBushkin..

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**

When you perform ***INSERT INTO Target_Table SELECT FROM source_table ORDER BY COL1***
order by clause is not considered, because order by is not allowed in inner query.
So in your query even if you specify order by a column it will not be considered. Part of query other then order by will be executed.
Try putting the select query in the brackets, it will give you an error that ORDER BY is not allowed in sub query.

If you have any Clustered Index on a columns of the table and you bulk insert on such table, data will be inserted in ascending order of clustered Index column.

So if you have any Clustered Index on columns **Sr_No** of the **R_G_23** table then, data will be inserted in ascending order of **Sr_no** column of **R_G_23** table. Even if you specify any order by clause it is of no use.

What you can try is apply clustered Index on the column by which you want to sort the data in table **Temp_R_G_23** or **R_G_23** and then execute the query.

Once you apply clustered index on target Table, whatever data you insert in the table, it will be ordered by the index key.

**Solution 2:**

If you do not want to create any index than what you can do is
First insert the data from source table to a temporary table, using below given sample query for sorting data.

SELECT * INTO TEMP#

FROM (

select [NO] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.Sr_No asc ),Sr_No, Date, Item_Code, Item_Name, Received_Qty, Invoice_No
 from Temp_R_G_23 t1

) AS X

After this insert data to destination table from the TEMP# table by specifying column names

INSERT INTO R_G_23 (Sr_No, Date, Item_Code, Item_Name, Received_Qty, Invoice_No

select Sr_No, Date, Item_Code, Item_Name, Received_Qty, Invoice_No from TEMP#